# Updating fragment ui periodically

Tags: android, android-fragments, timer

I have in my main activity a method that periodically updates data from the database like this:

```
    public static void timedTask(int timer) {
    myTimer.cancel();
    myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

         dbint =   db.dbpull();
        }
    }, 0, timer);
}
```

Now the problem is, how can I pass the value I get from this method, and update a TextView inside a fragment with the data?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have fragment defined in Activity layout with id `example_fragment`
so we can instance of fragment

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
```

and can create method in Fragment class to update data

```
public void updateFragment(Data ..){
          // update view
}
```

and in side your activity

```
fragment.updateFragment(data ..);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to put the timer inside the `Fragment` in `onCreateView()`.

So, when you connect the fragment to its view you start the timer (you can save a timestamp in the `SharedPreferences` to allow consistency across activities/fragments life cycle). As you create the timer inside the fragment, after it expires you can access the `TextView` directly from within the timer callback.

Just make sure you deactivate the timer in `onDestroyView()`.

Comment: I would prefer keeping the timer inside a method since i want to be able to change the timer dynamically.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from canceling and recreating the timer every time you need to dynamically change its time (there is practically no penalty for doing it again and again). So you can add the cancel and reschedule method inside the Fragment.